# jQuery Form plugin submit several forms but wait until previous has ended

Tags: jquery-forms-plugin

Users are abled to add new forms which are all submited with one button click and "jQuery Form plugin". To submit each form I iterate over forms which have a certain class.

As the users can submit images and the server has to do some work with each Image I´d like to wait until the previous submit has finished with a success statusText. Currently (I just do a timeout of 2000 which is nothing more than a "hackish" solution.)

I think I can use success function for this but do not know how I connect my submit loop with the returned success statusText. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mj9dbLh1/2/).
Here what I have:

```
 var userform =  '<form class="myForm" action="up.php" method="post"> ' +
                        'Name: <input type="text" name="name" />'  +
                        'file: <input type="file" name="img[]" multiple />'  +
                        'Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea>' +
                        '<input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />' +
                    '</form>';


    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, form) {
        if (statusText === "success") {
            console.log("the submit ended with success");
            //submit next form should happen
        }
    }

    var options = {
        success: showResponse
    };

    $('#add').click(function() {
        $(userform).appendTo('.append').each(function() {
            $('.myForm').ajaxForm(options);
        });
    });


    $("#all").click(function() {
    var collection = $('.myForm');
    if (collection.length > 0) {
        var i = 0;
        var fn = function() {
            var element = $(collection[i]);
            $(element).submit().addClass('done').hide("slow");
            if (++i < collection.length) {
                setTimeout(fn, 2000);
            }
        };
        fn();
    }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The submit handler simply does a std POST/GET so you aren't going to get a response back. You are going to want to change your code to use ajax and then have the server return a response of `success = true/false` or whatever you prefer

https://jsfiddle.net/mj9dbLh1/3/

Change this...

```
var element = $(collection[i]);
$(element).submit().addClass('done').hide("slow");
if (++i < collection.length) {
    setTimeout(fn, 2000);
}
```

To something like...

```
var element = $(collection[i]);
$(element).addClass('done').hide("slow");
$.post("ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    fn(); // DO SUCCESS ACTION HERE
});
```

Keep in mind this will execute on each success SO you may want to first get a count of the number of forms (which gives you the number of ajax calls). Then increment that count for each success action. Once you get your total you can Display ALL SUCCESS.

Take a look at these docs for more clues on how to handle errors and what not.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Hi ductiletoaster, thanks for your answer, two questions. your solutions fires hundreds of requests how can I stop this that only a new request is fired on success. Further you say I do not get a responds back with my submits but isn´t this exactly what the success function is for? it gives me the returned val on success. thanks!

Comment: Disregard. I was seeing the two onClick events as completely separate. My answer no longer makes sense.